# PHP: Check, what array values are greater than 1 (duplicates etc.)

Tags: php, arrays, string

There is an array:

```
Array
(
    [Apple] => 1
    [Banana] => 2
    [Orange] => 1
    [Pie] => 3
)
```

I'd like to check, what array values are greater than 1 (duplicates etc.) and return them.

```
'Banana was found 2 times in the array, Pie even 3 times.
```

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: I should have mentioned, that I was looking for a solution as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use array_filter to filter an array based on key/value. It returns an array with only what matched your criteria in the call back function.

```
$greaterThanOne = array_filter($array, function($val){ return ($val > 1); });

foreach($greaterThanOne as $fruit=>$count){
    echo "$fruit was found $count times in the array.<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have to iterate the array...

```
foreach ($array_with_fruits as $fruit=>$times){
    if ($times>1) { echo $fruit." was found ".$times." times"; }
}
```